# Ordering product only once Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce, rules, users

I'm just creating a commerce site in drupal. There are 25+ products in my site. Currently, a single user can able to check out the same product for multiple times. I want to restrict that. If a user buys one product means, he might not be able to buy the same product next time. Is there any way to do this???

Thanks.

Comment: Simply add a product reference field to each user. On checkout complete, add that product to the field. Create a pricing rule that sets the price to NULL (effectively disabling the add-to-cart) on the condition that the user has the product in their "only buy once" field. Finally, use field permissions module to restrict that field to administrators.

Comment: Hi @joshmiller . That is an interesting method, thanks for sharing. I accomplished the same thing before by creating a rule that restricts the quantity of the product of the certain type to 1 upon adding to cart, then in custom module performed a check if user bough the product before - and if yes then disable "add to cart" button and change it's text to something like "already purchased" or to whatever the context requires. That's for clarity while user sees product display after completing an order.

Comment: Additional rule would also perform checks and delete the product from cart w/ appropriate message to cover the scenario when anonymous user adds product to the cart and then logs in with an account that already purchased that product before. I might give your method a try next time I do something like that, seems like it may save some time and allow for additional functionality for reporting.